# Bash user input to run a script from user input that many times

Tags: bash, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to get a number from 1 to 10 from the user that will use that number to run a specific script that amount of times from the user input. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e79V3.png)

Comment: Please restate your question. I can't tell what you are asking.

Comment: Also people want to see what you have tried so far. It's much easier to help when you give example code that demonstrates where you are stuck.

Comment: Please don't post links, pictures of text, or links to pictures of text. Pictures are not searchable, not readable by screen readers, and take up bandwidth. Links become obsolete. Post actual text instead.

Comment: sorry wont happen again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this (assuming the script you want to run multiple times is called scritp_to_run_multiple_time.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash

function get_user_number {
    echo -n "Enter a number between 1 and 10 [ENTER]: "
    read number
    if [ "$number" -le 0 -o "$number" -ge 11 ]
    then
    get_user_number
    fi
}

get_user_number
for i in $(seq 1 $number); do
    scritp_to_run_multiple_time.sh
done
```